# HTTP Streaming - Number of flows

Tags: http-streaming

I'm currently doing a research about simple HTTP Streaming without dinamic adaptation in terms of debit and I came across one exercice.

The topology would consist in a Server, streaming a video to several Clients through VLC. One of the Clients would be using VLC, the other Firefox by creating an HTML page with the video on it and the last one using ffmeg.

It then asks that we start with the VLC Client, take a Wireshark capture, then without turning off the first Client, to start the Firefox one, take another capture and do exactly the same with the third one, where all 3 would be running.

Now the question it asks is what's the number of flows for each of the captures. What is this refering to?

Is a flow refering to the quintuplet (src ip, dest ip, src port, dest port, protocol)? How do I find the exact number using Wireshark?

Answer (score 0):

> Is a flow refering to the quintuplet (src ip, dest ip, src port, dest port, protocol)? How do I find the exact number using Wireshark?

Yes

> How do I find the exact number using Wireshark?

There are a number of options available under the Statistics menu.